# How to "transpose" a list of vectors?

Tags: r, list, transpose

I have a list of vectors:

```
asdf = list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
```

Now I want to "transpose" it, that is, obtain a list of 5 pairs instead of a pair of lists of 5.

To be more specific, I want the result to be analogous to the result of typing:

```
transposedAsdf = list(c(1, 10), c(2, 20), c(3, 30), c(4, 40), c(5, 50))
```

But I don't know how to achieve this. How to?

Comment: Why don't you make this a matrix?

Answer (score 9):

One option with `Map` from `base R`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = c, asdf))
```

Answer (score 7):

An option using `data.table`

```
data.table::transpose(asdf)
#[[1]]
#[1]  1 10

#[[2]]
#[1]  2 20

#[[3]]
#[1]  3 30

#[[4]]
#[1]  4 40

#[[5]]
#[1]  5 50
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

asdf2 <- transpose(asdf) %>% map(unlist)
asdf2
# [[1]]
# [1]  1 10
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  2 20
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  3 30
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  4 40
# 
# [[5]]
# [1]  5 50
```

Answer (score 3):

```
transposedAsdf = as.list(as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(asdf))))
transposedAsdf
$V1
[1]  1 10

$V2
[1]  2 20

$V3
[1]  3 30

$V4
[1]  4 40

$V5
[1]  5 50
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
split(do.call(cbind, asdf), 1:length(asdf[[1]]))
# $`1`
# [1]  1 10
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  2 20
# 
# $`3`
# [1]  3 30
# 
# $`4`
# [1]  4 40
# 
# $`5`
# [1]  5 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Package `collapse` has `t_list` for "Efficient List Transpose"

```
collapse::t_list(asdf)
# $V1
# [1]  1 10
#
# $V2
# [1]  2 20
#
# $V3
# [1]  3 30
#
# $V4
# [1]  4 40
# 
# $V5
# [1]  5 50
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sapply` and `asplit`:

```r
asplit(sapply(asdf, `[`, 1:5), 1)
```

```r
[[1]]
[1]  1 10

[[2]]
[1]  2 20

[[3]]
[1]  3 30

[[4]]
[1]  4 40

[[5]]
[1]  5 50
```